# How to show special characters on Apple App Store product description?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I see with some apps like Toodledo they use checkmarks for their revision history.  How can you show/use special characters in an App Store product description?  Does it allow HTML or do you just have to use ascii character codes?

Any tips/tricks for better presentation of our app's product information?

Thank you.

Comment: Update (Apr 2013)e: it seems, that Apple has put restrictions on usage of special characters. You can no more use 'star', 'finger' etc.

Comment: Ascii? You mean unicode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply enter the characters using the character table in OS X.

To show it, go to OS X System Preferences -> International and select "Show Input Sources in Menu Bar". You should get a flag symbol next to the clock in the menu bar. Clicking on it results in a menu where you can open the character table, in which you can select and paste pretty much any character.

Comment: In OSX Lion it is slightly different ... goto System Preferences -> Language & Text and select the "Input Sources" table.  Check off "Show  Input menu in menu bar".  You'll have a new menu icon in the top menu bar.  Clicking it provides 2 options "Show Character Viewer" and "Show Keyboard Viewer" - click the later and you get the Character viewer you need.

Comment: In OS X Mountain Lion is different again: go to Preferences > Keyboard and check "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar". Click on the new icon in the menu bar and select "Show Character Viewer".

Comment: To enter Emoji characters on OS X Mavericks simply hold Command-Control-Space whenever you are in a text field and an Emoji panel will appear.

Answer (score 21):

I think Apple just made the rule stricter on the App Store. I have been using special characters in my metadatas for a very long time but got a bad surprise today when trying to submit a new version:

Got this error message on iTunes Connect:

```
What's New In This Version must not contain the following characters: ★, ❤
```

Comment: Same here! Trying to submit today....no more special characters. All I wanted was a simple checkmark. :(

Comment: Same here. Is this a bug or a new restriction?

Comment: @StefanArn clearly a new restriction I believe. You can still use the • bullet but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 8):

I am the author of the Toodledo app. Here is how I did it.  I found the character I wanted on the internet by searching for "unicode symbols". I found it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_(check_mark))

I then copy and pasted the checkmark ✓ into my app description.  And every time I need to make a new checkmark, I go and copy and paste it again since I don't know how to type it.  There are lots of interesting symbols to choose from.  I also use a star★

Comment: i've noticed the star doesn't seem to work on the actual device. it lists the unicode &#... instead of the symbol

Comment: Apple has removed the ability to use special characters in app descriptions :(

Answer (score 0):

[UnicodeChecker](http://www.earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/) is an excellent Mac app that contains a database of over 100,000 characters defined in Unicode. You can search for characters by their assigned English names. For example, search for "check" to find several kinds of checkmark characters. Once found, you can copy a character and paste into your description.

UnicodeChecker is free of cost.

[image]

Comment: Why not use the Character Viewer built into OS X? System Prefs, Keyboard: Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar. From the menubar you click the helper icon and Show character viewer. Now pick all the characters you desire..

Comment: @Gatada The `Show Character Viewer` feature is nice. Think of `UnicodeChecker` as a heavy-duty version of that *Viewer*. UnicodeChecker provides those features and more. More information: those four tabs in screen shot display all of the data from the official Unicode database. Easier to find characters by number. That popup menu in upper-right corner displays a list of fonts containing a glyph for that character. See the decomposition (sequence of characters separating out main character from diacriticals as is done in ["normalized"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) text).