# App Store description Unicode?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I've heard that you can use Unicode in the descriptions for your app in iTunes Connect, but I can't find any real reference on how to do it. Do they support all Unicode characters? How do you do it, write U+#### or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, just paste the character into iTunes Connect.  No need for the U+ code

Comment: Thanks, I figured I'd give that a try just after I posted the question. Hopefully it will come out ok.

Comment: There are restrictions on using certain characters (like stars and ticks) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484501/how-to-show-special-characters-on-apple-app-store-product-description#16187744

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check it up in iTunes Connect? I'm pretty sure they support Unicode descriptions not only because of the many languages in the App Store. Also many special chars are used in some descriptions so I am saying *yes*.